# How to block/restrict specific URL in CefSharp WinForms C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, browser, cefsharp

Hope you all are doing good.

I have created the Webbrowser using CefSharp in WindowsForm of C#. Now I want to restrict/Block a specific URL to render in the browser due to some privacy other than that I don't want to restrict anything just want to restrict the specific URL and I'm unable to find the solution how to do that in Winform C#. Kindly help me with how to do that by sharing a piece of code.

My code is here and doesn't know how to restrict URL haven't added any kind of code in that for restriction

```
    public partial class Browser : Form
    {
        public Browser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Browser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            //Initialization
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            var url = "https://www.humanatic.com/pages/humfun/login.cfm";
            ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url);
            chrome.Parent = tabControl.SelectedTab;
            chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        private void BtnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as ChromiumWebBrowser;
            if (chrome != null)
            {
                if (chrome.CanGoBack)
                    chrome.Back();
            }
        }

        private void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as ChromiumWebBrowser;
            if (chrome != null)
            {
                if (chrome.CanGoForward)
                    chrome.Forward();
            }
        }

        private void BtnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as ChromiumWebBrowser;
            if (chrome != null)
                chrome.Refresh();
        }

        private void BtnNewTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabPage tab = new TabPage();
            tab.Text = "New Tab";
            tabControl.Controls.Add(tab);
            tabControl.SelectTab(tabControl.TabCount - 1);
            ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com");
            chrome.Parent = tab;
            chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            chrome.TitleChanged += Chrome_TitleChanged;
        }

        private void Chrome_TitleChanged(object sender, TitleChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                tabControl.SelectedTab.Text = e.Title;
            }));
        }

        private void Browser_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Permission!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

API doc is [here](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/86.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_Handler_RequestHandler_OnBeforeBrowse.htm).

```cs
//Cancel loading of a Url
public class CustomRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.RequestHandler
{
    protected override bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool userGesture, bool isRedirect)
    {
        //For security reasons you should perform validation on the url to confirm that it's safe before proceeding.
        if (request.Url.StartsWith("http://www.google.com"))
        {
            //Cancel the request
            return true;
        }
        return base.OnBeforeBrowse(chromiumWebBrowser, browser, frame, request, userGesture, isRedirect);
    }
}

browser.RequestHandler = new CustomRequestHandler();
```

Comment: Hi @amaitland, Thanks for responding.
Firstly, the API link is not working.
Secondly, I'm getting error on the below line of code
browser.RequestHandler = new CustomRequestHandler();

Comment: API link works fine, for me, Please check again. What is the actual error you are seeing?